# How to extract the private key and Certificate from pfx?

Tags: delphi, openssl, crypt, pkcs#12

I'm trying to read the private key and the certificate of a .PFX file.
I need both to Sign a message using the MimeSign method of this Unit (https://github.com/cybexr/Delphi-unit-OpenSSL/blob/master/OpenSSLUtils.pas).
I'm using this code

```
procedure ReadKeyFromPFX(PFXFileName: TFileName);    
 var
     Certfile: pBIO;
     PFX: pPKCS12;
     PCert : PX509;
     POtherCerts : pSTACK_OFX509;
     PKey  : pEVP_PKEY;
     Sucesso : Integer;
  begin
     Certfile := BIO_new(BIO_s_file());
     BIO_read_filename(Certfile, PAnsiChar(AnsiString(PFXFileName)));
     PFX := d2i_PKCS12_bio(Certfile, nil);
     Sucesso := PKCS12_parse(PFX, nil , PKey, PCert, POtherCerts);
     fCertificate := PCert;
     fKey         := PKey;
  end;
```

Sucesso returns 0 and according to the openssl documentation that means an error (https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/man3/PKCS12_parse.html), but if I call `ERR_error_string(ERR_get_error, @ErrMsg);` all I get is this

[image: error]

Comment: I don't know that library, but with so many zeroes in the error, it looks like some library/dll cannot be loaded. Does your library maybe depend on openSSL dlls? And it can find those? Not just the libaey.pas unit but also [the dll](https://indy.fulgan.com/SSL/)?

Comment: Yes. It uses libeay

Comment: Reading the doc, it seems this is the description for error 0. 0 is returned from ERR_get_error when there are no more errors in the queue, indicating that nothing went wrong. That collides with the 0 in Sucesso, of course...
I can't really see what is wrong, but maybe you could try using `TX509Certificate.LoadFromFile`, which seems to do what you are doing, but with a bit more handling around it.

Comment: OK. I will try and share the results here. Thank You

Comment: I found this as well, to achieve  similar result [using the openSSL CLI](https://www.ssl.com/how-to/export-certificates-private-key-from-pkcs12-file-with-openssl/). Maybe not what you're looking for for your final solution, but at least it may provide some insight on what is wrong either in your code or with the .pfx file.

Comment: Are you sure the Delphi interface correspond to the actual OpenSSL version you are using? Maybe try with ICS which has translation for the latest OpenSSL libraries. In ICS distribution, look for f_PKCS12_parse (Defined in OverbyteIcsLIBEAY and used in OverbyteIcsWSocket). Download source from http://wiki.overbyte.be